# i updated my project from dotnet 2.1 to 6 and some base repository function return 500

Tags: c#, .net-core

[error in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ll9s.png)

[im trying to do sothing like this but need help with how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udEWU.png)

upgrate my project from dotnet 2.1 to 6

my base function now return 500

using vscode

i need to check if IsActive property is exist in that model from base repo that im using generic model

```
 public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TPickerDto>> GetForPickerAsync([Optional] List<string> fieldsForInclude, [Optional] Dictionary<string, ItemsPermissions> permissions)
        {
            IQueryable<TModel> listFromDb = this._context.Set<TModel>()
                .Where(r => (r.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive") != null &&
                        r.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive").GetValue(r) != null &&
                        (bool)r.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive").GetValue(r) == true) ||
                        (r.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive") == null) ||
                        (r.GetType().GetProperty("IsActive").GetValue(r) == null));

            if (permissions != null)
            {
                if (permissions.ContainsKey("allowedUnits") && permissions.ContainsKey("allowedSites"))
                {

                    if (permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").All && !permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").All)
                    {
                        listFromDb = listFromDb.Where(r => r.GetType().GetProperty("SiteId").GetValue(r) == null
                            || permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").Indexes.Contains((int)r.GetType().GetProperty("SiteId").GetValue(r)));
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (!permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").All && permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").All)
                        {
                            listFromDb = listFromDb.Where(r => r.GetType().GetProperty("UnitId").GetValue(r) == null
                                || permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").Indexes.Contains((int)r.GetType().GetProperty("UnitId").GetValue(r)));
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            if (!permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").All && !permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").All)
                            {
                                listFromDb = listFromDb.Where(r => (r.GetType().GetProperty("UnitId").GetValue(r) == null
                                        || permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").Indexes.Contains((int)r.GetType().GetProperty("UnitId").GetValue(r)))
                                    && (r.GetType().GetProperty("SiteId").GetValue(r) == null
                                        || permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").Indexes.Contains((int)r.GetType().GetProperty("SiteId").GetValue(r))));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    if (permissions.ContainsKey("allowedUnits"))
                    {
                        listFromDb = listFromDb
                            .Where(r => permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").All
                                || r.GetType().GetProperty("UnitId").GetValue(r) == null
                                || permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedUnits").Indexes.Contains((int)r.GetType().GetProperty("UnitId").GetValue(r)));
                    }
                    if (permissions.ContainsKey("allowedSites"))
                    {
                        listFromDb = listFromDb
                            .Where(r => permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").All
                                || r.GetType().GetProperty("SiteId").GetValue(r) == null
                                || permissions.GetValueOrDefault("allowedSites").Indexes.Contains((int)r.GetType().GetProperty("SiteId").GetValue(r)));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Import all the navigation properties 
            if (fieldsForInclude != null)
            {
                listFromDb = _JoinNavigationProperties(listFromDb, fieldsForInclude);
            }

            IEnumerable<TPickerDto> mappingList = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TPickerDto>>(listFromDb);

            return mappingList;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `dotnet core 3`, Ef will throw an exception if a Linq query couldn't be translated to SQL and results in `Client-side evaluation`. In earlier versions you would just receive a warning. You will need to improve your `Linq` query so that it can be evaluated on client side.

Refer to this link for details,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

You are using reflection to do the query, why not use the property directly? If your `boolean` can be be `NULL` then declare the type as `bool? IsActive`. That way you can check for null in the where,

```
this._context.Set<TModel>().Where(r => (r.IsActive==true))
```

In case you are trying to create a repository then try declaring an interface that has IsActive as a field.

```cs
interface ISoftDeleteTarget
{
    public IsActive{get;}
}
```

Comment: i need to check if IsActive property is exist in that model from base repo that im using generic model